# Django : Access model data in template using Class-based generic views

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to display the model data in the template.
When I don't have any filtering, it works fine!

```
class UserLogList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'data'
    queryset = UserLog.objects.all().values('user_id__username','event_id','time')
```

But if I want to have some filtering, example if I want to get the details based on the user_id where user_id = 1. I can get the user id from the `request` object or `self.request` object.

So to achieve this, I did the following in my `views.py`

```
class DisplayUserActivity(ListView):
    template_name = 'user_activity.html'
    uid = self.request.user.id

    def get_object(self):
        uid = self.request.user.id
        object = super(DisplayUserActivity,self).get_object()
        object.data = UserLog.objects.filter(user_id = uid).values('user_id__username','event_id','time')
        return object
```

and my `template` file:

```
{% block content %}
        <h2> Logs </h2>
                <table border="1" style="width:50%">
                        <tr>
                                <th> User Name </th>
                                <th> Description </th>
                                <th> Time </th>
                        </tr>
                                {% for user in data %}
                        <tr>
                                        <td> {{user.user_id__username}}</td>
                                        <td> {{user.event_id}}</td>
                                        <td> {{user.time}} </td>
                                {% endfor %}
                        </tr>
                </table>
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a method called [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) instead of `get_object` when extending the generic ListView.

EDIT:

Regarding your edit, theres an issue with your template

```
{% for user in data %}
```

should be

```
{% for user in object_list %}
```

But I suspect there are deeper problems here which are hard to decipher. My advice is to look through your code and the Django documentation more carefully, and possibly switch to a custom written view until you are more comfortable. :)

Comment: I tried it, didn't get through!

`def get_queryset(self):
                uid = int(self.request.user.id)
                context_object_name = 'return UserLog.objects.all()`

Comment: @RohitPujar Your code formatting is messed up, I can't read it. But one issue I just noticed on your original answer `uid` is not in scope, you need to use `self.request.uid` in the get_queryset method, as @alecxe pointed out

Comment: Sorry,missed that while putting the question. That's not the problem though!

Comment: I have given `context_object_name = 'data'` and so I think it should be fine, isn't it?

Comment: @RohitPujar not positive off-hand, but I don't think that applies to `ListView`, just `DetailView`

Comment: I had declared `context_object_name = 'data'` in the method instead in class level which is why it wasn't able to fetch anything. I had the code proper in the question,but wrong in the actual code, my dumbness!